# Generate password Hash with SHA1+salt and MD4

Tags: linux, hash, cryptography, password-encryption, password-hash

Anyone know how to generate Hashes with the command line on Linux?
I have to generate a Hash with SHA1 + salt=  Password:Cat Salt:XN10Zj2c
and a Hash with MD4= Password:Cat

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that there is no generic way of hashing a password and a salt. In all likelihood you need to mimic the `crypt` command line tool, as it doesn't contain these algorithms (hence I've used -1 and -2 as algorithm identifiers instead).

For instance:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Your password and salt
password="your_password_here"
salt="your_salt_here"

# Specify the algorithm: -1 for MD4, -2 for SHA-1
algorithm_specifier="-2" # Change this to -1 for MD4

# Function to hash with SHA-1
hash_sha1() {
    local pass="$1"
    local salt="$2"
    echo -n "$pass$salt" | openssl dgst -sha1
}

# Function to hash with MD4
hash_md4() {
    local pass="$1"
    local salt="$2"
    echo -n "$pass$salt" | openssl dgst -md4
}

# Check for the specified hashing algorithm
if [ "$algorithm_specifier" == "-2" ]; then
    # SHA-1 hashing
    sha1_hash=$(hash_sha1 "$password" "$salt")
    echo "$algorithm_specifier$$salt$$sha1_hash"
elif [ "$algorithm_specifier" == "-1" ]; then
    # MD4 hashing
    md4_hash=$(hash_md4 "$password" "$salt")
    echo "$algorithm_specifier$$salt$$md4_hash"
else
    echo "Invalid algorithm specifier."
fi
```

Note that the `$` signs are used to separate the different parts of the output within the "`crypt` format". However, they are not part of what is actually hashed. Also, `crypt` normally hashes the password followed by the salt, not the other way around.

---

However, please note that you should use neither of these old, broken hashes **nor** should you use a newer hash such as SHA-2 or SHA-3. The reason for this is that you should be using a PBKDF such as PBKDF2 or Argon2 with a high iteration count or work factor and preferably a 16 byte random salt. These functions are sometimes also called "password hashes" and with good reason; they provide additional protection against brute force and dictionary attacks.